# while compiling: INSERT INTO tabellirik(judul,lirikpupuh) VALUES (?,?)

Tags: android

i have problem with my sqlite

```
error table tabellirik has no column named judul (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tabellirik(judul,lirikpupuh) VALUES (?,?)
```

i have same error, and i have question, where location file database sqlite if i debug application, im using Android Studio?

please help me :)

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Macepat";

    private static final String TABLE_MUPUH = "tabellirik";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    private static final String JUDUL = "judul";

    private static  final String KEY_MUPUH = "lirikpupuh";

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LIRIK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MUPUH + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + JUDUL + "TEXT,"
            + KEY_MUPUH + "TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LIRIK_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_MUPUH);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public int addLirik(Lirik lirik){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(JUDUL, lirik.getJudul());
        values.put(KEY_MUPUH, lirik.getLirik());
        int id = (int) db.insert(TABLE_MUPUH,null,values);
        db.close();
        return id;
    }

    public int editLirik(Lirik lirik, String position){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(JUDUL, lirik.getJudul());
        values.put(KEY_MUPUH, lirik.getLirik());
        return db.update(TABLE_MUPUH, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(position)});
    }

    public boolean deleteLirik(long IDlirik){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_MUPUH,KEY_ID + "= " + IDlirik, null)>0;
    }

    public Lirik getLirik(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MUPUH, new String[] { KEY_ID
    , JUDUL, KEY_MUPUH}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Lirik lirik = new Lirik(cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2));
        db.close();

        return lirik;
    }

    public  String[] getAllLirik(){
        ArrayList<String> lirikList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MUPUH;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    String lirik = cursor.getString(1) +" , "+ cursor.getString(2) + " , " + cursor.getString(3);
                    lirikList.add(lirik);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            String [] liriks = new String[lirikList.size()];
            db.close();
            return (lirikList.toArray(liriks));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is not created because you have missed some spaces on the `create` statement, and the `insert` cannot be compiled against a non-existing table:

```
String CREATE_LIRIK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MUPUH + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
    + JUDUL + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_MUPUH + " TEXT)";
```

Also, you have missed some spaces on the `drop` statement:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MUPUH);
```